Transformation properties of operator under $C$, $P$, and $T$ Inversions
I am studying the transformation properties of the following operator $$i \bar{\psi} \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 A_\nu D_{\mu} \psi$$ under the three symmetries: charge conjugation $C$, parity $P$, and time reversal $T$. I have successfully shown that under $P$ and $T$, the operator transforms as follows:
$$\mathcal{O} \xrightarrow{P} - \mathcal{O}$$
$$\mathcal{O} \xrightarrow{T} - \mathcal{O}$$
which means that the operator is conserved under $PT$.
According to the CPT theorem, since CPT must be conserved and the operator conserves $PT$, I would expect that it should also conserve $C$. However, upon applying the charge conjugation symmetry to the operator, I find the following transformation:
$$\mathcal{O} \xrightarrow{C} i (\partial + i e A)_\mu \bar{\psi} \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 \psi A_\nu$$
which means that the operator $\mathcal{O}$ does not have a well-defined value under charge conjugation.
My questions are as follows:

Is there a mistake in my calculation of any of the transformations?
If my calculations are correct, does this indicate that I cannot apply the CPT theorem in this context?
I understand that the operator is not gauge invariant, but afaik it is not a requirement for CPT. Must the operator have a well-defined C transformation for CPT to hold?

EDIT: As mentioned in the comments, the bilinear term in $A$ vanishes by symmetry, so the result is actually equal to $$\mathcal{O} \xrightarrow{C} i \partial_\mu \bar{\psi} \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 \psi A_\nu$$
however my questions remain the same.
As for using integration by parts, I can write
$$O^c = i \partial_\mu \bar{\psi} \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 \psi A_\nu \cong - i \bar{\psi} \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 \partial_\mu \psi A_\nu - i \bar{\psi} \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 \psi \partial_\mu A_\nu = - \mathcal{O} - \frac{i}{2} \bar{\psi} \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 \psi F_{\mu\nu}$$
The operator $\bar{\psi} \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 \psi F_{\mu\nu}$ is actually invariant under $C$, however I still don't see what are the implications for the original operator $\mathcal{O}$.

@CosmasZachos I don't understand what you mean, can you develop a little bit more?

You might connect with textbook tabulations more readily if you used $\sigma^{\nu\rho}\gamma^5=i \epsilon^{\sigma\mu\nu\rho} \sigma_{\sigma\mu}$.

Why does the photon bilinear survive in the original expression?

@CosmasZachos, Thanks for the suggestion. I actually used this relation when deriving the results, and I get the same results as when I do it directly with the gamma^5. Regarding the photon bilinear, you are 100% correct that it should vanish by the antisymmetry of sigma. However, this term is not the problematic one (if sigma were not antisymmetric, then this term would conserve C parity). The problematic term is precisely the derivative, since it acts on a different field than the initial one.

Have you integrated by parts?

@CosmasZachos, Yes, I've tried that. The result is not the original operator, since you then have an extra term where the derivative acts on the photon field. i.e., you get that the operator O goes to O -> -O + O', where O' is not related to the original operator (but O' is gauge invariant and conserves C by itself).

So why don't you consider ${\cal O}^c + {\cal O}$ instead?

@CosmasZachos Thanks for the idea, but my goal is to understand the behavior of the original operator $O$ under charge conjugation. Clearly considering $O^c+O$ would give an operator that conserves C parity, but I fail to see how can it help solving my questions.

The operator $O=i \bar{\psi} \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 A_\nu D_{\mu} \psi$ is NOT gauge invariant as a standalone operator. Do we usually consider gauge-invariant operators when it comes to C, P, T?

@MadMax Well, this would be related to my 2nd and 3rd questions, as far as I understand C, P and T symmetries should be completely independent of gauge symmetries. But I cannot find a gauge invariant operator with the same problems (I haven't tried too hard either)

After some thoughts I found a mostly satisfying answer, even though there is still a minor detail missing.
The answer is that $CPT$ theorem holds only for hermitian operators, which the operator $\mathcal{O}$ is not. Indeed, by defining a new operator as
$$\mathcal{O}' = \mathcal{O} + \mathcal{O}^\dagger$$
we obtain an operator that has the same transformations under parity and time-reversal. However now we have
$$\mathcal{O}^\dagger = i D^*_{\mu} \psi^\dagger A_\nu \gamma^5 \gamma^0 \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^0 \bar{\psi}^\dagger = - i D^*_{\mu} \bar{\psi} A_\nu \sigma^{\mu\nu} \gamma^5 \psi = -\mathcal{O}^c$$
which would give a well defined action under $C$:
$$\mathcal{O}' \xrightarrow{C} - \mathcal{O}'$$
Now, while this gives me a satisfactory answer on why CPT doesn't hold for $\mathcal{O}$ alone, I am still puzzled by the negative sign appearing from $C$ parity. It would seem that the operator $\mathcal{O}'$ violates $CPT$ (since it gets a negative sign for each one of the three symmetries), which should not be the case. I am guessing that this is probably only a mistake somewhere, but right now I cannot find it.
Any insights or corrections on this would be greatly appreciated!
